# Virtualbox not installing because of kernel version mismatch in fedora 20

Tags: linux, virtualbox, fedora, kernel

I am using [this](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/40926/trying-to-install-virtualbox-or-vmware-fedora-20/?answer=40927#post-id-40927) answer to install Vbox,The only problem I have is with kernel version in the second part of that answer it tells output of

```
uname -rm
```

and

```
rpm -qa kernel | sort -V | tail -n 1
```

should match but for me,they don't the output of uname -rm is :

> 3.15.10-201.fc20.i686+PAE i686

and the output of rpm -qa kernel | sort -V | tail -n 1 is

> kernel-3.16.7-200.fc20.i686

I tried to installing kernel-3.16.7-200.fc20.i686 with yum but I can't,I tried something like this:

```
sudo yum install kernel-3.16.7-200.fc20
```

here is the output of rpm -qa kernel

```
rpm -qa kernel

kernel-3.15.10-201.fc20.i686

kernel-3.16.6-203.fc20.i686

kernel-3.16.7-200.fc20.i686
```

So the question is,How Can I download and install kernel and set it to default in my fedora 20 and makes the outputs match

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running the following command

```
sudo grub2-install /dev/sda
```

I run it because I have several Linux installed and default grub was for ubuntu so when fedora installed a new kernel,it couldn't change it